# Callback for cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a Single Sign On system that requires communication between 2 servers. The child server send something to the parent server to validate, it it's valid, then register the user, if not, send back the error message, say "email exist in database already", etc.

I'm wondering that is there any way that I can do this in cURL?

So the child can send a validation request like:

> ```
>               $ch = curl_init();
>               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
>               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //this prevent printing the 200json code
>               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3); //timeout 1s
>               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); //timeout 1s
>               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
>               $result = curl_exec($ch);
>               curl_close($ch);
> ```

It seems that **"$result = curl_exec($ch);"** is the result(callback). It's simply 200 now. Is there a way I can pass the validation error/success via this or via other params of curl like a callback? How should I write the code in parent server(who is getting curled and going to send the response back)? Should I just do "**echo $error;**" to return the result to the child?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, `var_dump` it.

Comment: @DissidentRage It's simply 200 now. I wanted to know how to make it the validation error. So I can pass the validation error / success from the parent to the child.

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback in PHP. (almost) Everything is synchronous in PHP, while the callback principle is useful for asynchronous programming.

**update**: the function [curl_getInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-getinfo.php)() will give you more details about the last request.

Comment: Thanks! but how can i make $result something else than 200..? like how to pass an error here?

Comment: change the url to a fake one; or disconnect your network cable ;)

Comment: I updated my answer as I remember the existence of curl_getinfo()

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I'm asking that how can I pass an error message like "invalid username" from the parent server. Thanks for ur help!

Comment: just by returning the info you want to be transmitted. by example create a result object, with an isError() method, a code and a message, and fill them by using the info returned  by ssh_exec() or curl_get_info(). There is no standard way, it's up to you to decide.